# Как компилятор понимает, где одна переменная, а где другая?

Tags: java

```
public class User {

    String name;
    short age;
    int height;

    public User(int height, short age, String name) {
        this.height = height;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(int height, String name, short age) {
        this.height = height;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public User(short age, String name, int height) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public User(short age, int height, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(String name, int height, short age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public User(String name, short age, int height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user1 = new User("Dminem", (short)28, 182);
        User user2 = new User("Nemdim", 160, (short)32);
        System.out.println(user1.name + user1.height + user1.age);
        System.out.println(user2.name + user2.height + user2.age);
    }
}
```

Почему если при создании объектов указать перед значением (short), то компилятор понимает, в какую переменную записать это значение?

Почему такой же фокус не проходит, если указать (int) перед другим значением?

Comment: Java подбирает по типу данных которые Вы передаете. Второй случай не проходит ибо `int` больше чем `short`. А первый случай работает ибо у Вас есть конструктор который принимает `String`, `short` и `int` данные.

Comment: Какой именно фокус не проходит?

Comment: "фокус не проходит" - что значат эти слова? Вы получаете ошибку компиляции? Она секретная?

Comment: благодарю всех за обратную связь.

Comment: User user1 = new User("Dminem", 28, 182);
User user2 = new User("Nemdim", 160, 32); если убрать short вообще, то появляется такая ошибка при компилировании

Comment: Error:(48, 22) java: no suitable constructor found for User(java.lang.String,int,int)
    constructor com.company.User.User(int,short,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to int)
    constructor com.company.User.User(int,java.lang.String,short) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to int)
    constructor com.company.User.User(short,java.lang.String,int) is not applicable

Comment: (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to short)
    constructor com.company.User.User(short,int,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to short)
    constructor com.company.User.User(java.lang.String,int,short) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; possible lossy conversion from int to short)
    constructor com.company.User.User(java.lang.String,short,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; possible lossy conversion from int to short)

Comment: В ошибке довольно доходчиво написано, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Если делать так:

```
User user1 = new User("Dminem", 28, (int)182);
```

Или так

```
User user1 = new User("Dminem", 28, 182);
```

то в конструктор передаются два int. А конструктора для таких параметров нет. Потому фокус и не удается.

Предположим у нас есть два таких конструктора (и компилятор разрешает):

```
public User(int height, int age) {
        this.height = height;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

и

```
public User(int age, int height) {
        this.height = height;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

Теперь мы создаем такой объект

```
User user = new User(28, 182);
```

Откуда яве знать, какой конструктор здесь нужно использовать?
Потому такое и невозможно.

Comment: то есть по умолчанию все значения относятся к int, если явно не указано, что именно это значение относится к типу short? если бы класс состоял из 4 значений, два любых из которых были бы объявлены как int или как short, то уже не вышло бы их присвоить к нужным переменным?

Comment: Если бы были конфликтующие конструкторы, то думаю случилась бы ошибка при компиляции.

Comment: Неважно из чего "состоит класс". Дело здесь исключительно в типах параметров конструктора.

Comment: Вас понял, просто по условию задачи "Создайте для него необходимое количество конструкторов, чтобы имя, возраст и рост можно было указывать в любом порядке". Вот и возник вопрос, как выполнить данное условие в случае четырех параметров, если в конструкторе указать условно String, int age, int weight, short, допустим, а другой конструктор описывал бы String, int weight, int age, short.

Comment: Объявите рост как `double`.

Comment: а когда типы переменных будут исчерпаны?)

Comment: Возможен только один конструктор с каким-то данным порядком параметров. Тип не имеет значения, можно использовать хоть сто переменных одного типа. Но только в одном строго заданном порядке. Создавать по конструктору на всякий возможный порядок не имеет смысла и никто так не делает.

Comment: Эникейщик, спасибо, по конструктору на всякий возможный порядок не имеет смысла - понимаю, интересовал теоретический вариант подобного для выполнения поставленной задачи. Спасибо всем за комментарии!

Answer (score 0):

> а когда типы переменных будут исчерпаны?

```
public class Height {
  private int value;
  private Height(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public int getValue() { return value; }

  public static Height of(int value) {
    return new Height(value);
  }
}
```

Аналогично - для `Age`.

```
public User(String name, Height height, Age age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height.getValue();
    this.age = age.getValue();
}
public User(String name, Age age, Height height) {
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height.getValue();
    this.age = age.getValue();
}

...
User user2 = new User("Nemdim", Height.of(160), Age.of(32));
User user1 = new User("Dminem", Age.of(28), Height.of(182));
```